# Change multiple custom properties simultaneously

Tags: rigging, transforms, custom-properties

When I <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> on a transformations property, I can change the property for multiple objects with one input action. The property turns blue for the duration of the operation.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to make this work for custom properties?

Comment: While it is possible to use "Alt"+LMB on values like rotation, you can also use the right-click menu and "Copy to selected" or it's variations like "Copy to all selected" and "Copy single to selected" while the first is easy to understand the latter i didn't yet figure out the difference of. That said, the custom property value does not have that option of "Copy to selected", thus i believe there is a differentiation inside Blender that may as well be reason why the "Alt"+LMB combination is not working there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible by selecting both of the object. For a simple reason, one of the object may not have the property.

If you want to change multiple property at once you can add a driver between the property of the two (or many) objects.

Comment: You can change mesh or lamp specific properties for example even if other object types are selected though

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos How are mesh or lamp _specific_ properties the same as _user defined custom_ properties on an object?

Comment: They are the same regarding the possibility of different objects having them or not. That may not be the reason you can't mass edit them with `Alt` key, probably just that the properties are not "the same" despite sharing a name.

Comment: But that's the exact point that the answer is all about. When you select multiple objects, and some are let's say point lamps and some are UV spheres. If you edit the power of the light source with the Alt key, than the value changes for all the point lamps although you also have UV spheres selected. Because these are object specific properties and Blender knows, all point lamps have these properties so it can change them on all objects of the same kind. The custom properties are defined on a certain object and there is no default setting for other objects (if the object data is not linked).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that custom properties are dynamically appended to only one specific instance of a class and thus not part of any base or super class like the location & rotation properties which Blender can easily recognize & compare as being the same common property. So a custom property with the name "prop" on one instance is not really the same "prop" on the duplicated instance because it's also just appended again with the same name.

In order to have the same behavior implemented, Blender would have to check the names of the properties but that would not make any sense because 2 objects could possibly have the same custom property name but be of different data type. As already mentioned, you could use [`Drivers`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html) as a workaround.

Comment: Well maybe blender could check both the property name and its data type and conclude it is the same property? :D still sounds hacky.