# How to copy extrude/bevel data across multiple curve objects?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have imported 100 SVG objects (curves), these objects all need to have the exact extrude and bevel amounts.

I am not able to use <kbd>CNTRL + L</kbd> to link object data or text data without changing the actual object.

Does anyone know a quicker way to do this to all my objects?

Perhaps a python script (or any other way that is quicker than manually doing this)?

Comment: can't you join them?

Comment: Doesn't "changing value of a property of the active curve while holding the Alt button" working for all the selected curves too?

Comment: @UanpisCardada Good Idea I guess I can do that.

Comment: @Carlo WOW, I just tried it. Works perfect. I never knew you could do that.

Comment: @Carlo if you want to make that an answer, I will make sure you get the checkmark, if not I will make an answer, that is a pretty handy trick.

Comment: Yep, it's pretty handy and it works in multiple areas of blender.  Feel free to post an aswer, I'm going to bed now. Here's a related quesition: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79541/change-multiple-custom-properties-simultaneously

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unset multiple values from Bezier objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/how-to-unset-multiple-values-from-bezier-objects)

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/bevel-and-resolution-multiple-selected-curves

Answer (score 8):

I want to thank @Carlo for this handy tip.

This can be used in many different areas of Blender (I will post more scenarios when I have time).

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> Select all the objects you want to change.
2. With the last object selected make sure you hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and change the properties. This should affect all the objects you had selected.

[image]

Comment: A true life saver!

Comment: This is a golden tip!